# How to change a column attribute with a link/button - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, controller

I am learning RoR and I'm currently trying to have an up-vote system implemented into my website. Users can log on and post comments on a forum and then upvote other comments on that forum.

**Controller code**

```
 def upvote
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment])
    @comment.update_attribute('upVote', @comment.upvote + 1)
    redirect_to :back
 end
```

**Link in show**

```
 <%= link_to 'Up Vote', comment_upvote_path(comment.id), method: :put %>
```

I tried substituting (comment.id) with comment to no avail.

**Routes**

```
get 'upvote', :to=>'comments#upvote'

resources :comments do
 put :upvote
end
```

The error that I'm getting happens when I click to upvote:

Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=

app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:26:in `upvote'
Request

Parameters:

{"_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"HNXyufzGsXi/SZoJsa+2uouMKVYlH6vYTHOF8iMgj6zAHO13jApk+QO33xEonkcoFgMugwYQZpSom1+KbVRe7g==",
 "comment_id"=>"11"}

I checked and a comment with the id of 11 exists, so I really do not know what is causing this error. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, `:comment` should be `:comment_id` like so.

```
@comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
```

Comment: Ah yes thank you very much, can't believe I didn't see that. I'm now getting:  undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass  . So I assume I should use some sort of increment method rails already has for me.

Comment: @EduardoTafner: That will be because you're starting from 0 which defaults to `nil:NilClass`. You can use `@comment.increment('upVote')` to increment by 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
put :upvote
```

Should be

```
put :upvote, on: :member
```